# How to communicate view and controller in a php project with out any type of framework

Tags: php, jquery, url-routing

**Backgroud / Idea**
I am creating a web aplication from scratch; with out any type of php framework.
I am creating the web application in this way; because i want to LEARN php; and i think
that use a php framework do not will mame me a good php developer.

**What i did so far?**
I create a project structure:

- Project

  - css
  - script
  - Models
  - Controllers
  - Views
  - Resource

I created one view like:

```
<html>

<head>

<!-- here i call my jquery.js -->

<script>

...

function action()
(
...
    $.ajax(url: "/Controllers/HomeController.php", type:"POST",DataType:"JSON",Parameter:{var1:$("#var1").val(),method:"singup"})
    {...}
...
)

...

</script>

</head>

<body>

<input id="var1" name="var1" type="text">
<input id"mybutton" name="mybutton" type="button" onclick="action();">

</body>

</html>
```

In my HomeController.php

```
<?php

if(if(is_set($POST('method'))))
{
   if(function_exist($POST('method')))
   {   
      switch($POST('method'))
      {
          case "singup":
                $var1 = $POST('var1')
                singup($var1);
                break;
            ...
          default: break;
      }
   }
}

function singup($var1)
{
  $array = {"var1" => $var1};
  json_decode($array,1);
}

?>
```

**Questions**

I am not really sure about this code (security). I want to know:
What is the recommended way make call between views and controllers with out
use any type of php framework ?

Comment: Your syntax is all wrong. Perhaps a decent lightweight framework plus a book, would be a good place to study from.

Answer (score 0):

I myself like to have all this events and ajax calls within JS files, and as you are using a MVC like structure try having having a logic that handle URI routes like.

```
/controller/method/param1/param2
```

that way you would have a better code structure your above code then would refer to something like.

```
/home/signup/param1......
```

For this you would have to first get the URL divide it into segments for example.

```
$controller = $segment[0] 
$method = $segment[1] 
$params = ... the rest of the segments
```

here then you could have a check to see if the controller and method exists, and if the method has the given number of parameters. Try having a look at the laravel framework source code as they great work, I bet there's a couple of thinks you can pick out of it.

Comment: Thanks! well i found knockoutjs [knockoutjs-php](http://wern-ancheta.com/blog/2012/12/26/building-a-registration-system-with-knockoutjs/); my doubt in my code was have the php file name and my method visible in a javascript function. See the tutorial ... in $.Ajax(... data: {'student' : person, 'action' : 'insert'}, ...) the name of the action (method is located) is placed. Is it safe? Is this a good practice?

Answer (score -1):

Well, I'm not sure if i read your question correctly but...

in your controller you do all the PHP stuff then when you want to load your view you can use the

`include` command to load your html.php page. This way your PHP variables are exposed to your view.

But if your learning, it doesn't hurt to crack open an existing framework and look around to see what approach they took.

Also, in my framework I create a folder called "assets" and i include all the css, img, and js directories in it.

As for any framework, I'll share with your the snippet i use to get the URI and pull out the controller,action, and params

```
self::$_params = explode('/', rawurldecode(trim(parse_url(getenv('REQUEST_URI'), PHP_URL_PATH), '/')));

            $scope = array_shift(self::$_params);

$pre = null;
            $pre = strlen(self::$_controller) > 1 && is_numeric(self::$_controller[0]) ? 'n' : null;
            $pre = strlen(self::$_controller) > 1 && self::$_controller[0] == '-' ? 'd' : $pre;

            self::$_controller = $pre . preg_replace('/-/', '_', self::$_controller) . '_Controller';
            self::$_callAction = array_shift(self::$_params);

            if (empty(self::$_callAction) ||  self::$_callAction == '-')
            {
                self::$_callAction = 'indexAction';

            } else {

                $pre = strlen(self::$_callAction) > 1 && is_numeric(self::$_callAction[0]) ? 'n' : $pre;
                $pre = strlen(self::$_callAction) > 1 && self::$_callAction[0] == '_' ? 'u' : $pre;
                $pre = strlen(self::$_callAction) > 1 && self::$_callAction[0] == '-' ? 'd' : $pre;

                self::$_callAction = preg_replace('/-/', '_', self::$_callAction);
                self::$_callAction = $pre . self::$_callAction . 'Action';
            }
```